# Efficient way to draw paint using mouse on canvas

Tags: java, swing, awt, paint

I have a `Brush` class

```
 final class Brush
 {
  private final int size;
  private final Color color;
  private final Ellipse2D.Double blob=new Ellipse2D.Double();

  private Brush(int size,Color color)
  {
   this.size=size;
   this.color=color;
  }

  void paint(Graphics2D g2d,Point location)
  {
   g2d.setColor(color);    
   blob.setFrame(location.x-(size/2.0),location.y-(size/2.0),size,size);//Translate ecllipse so that the centre of it's bounding box is exactly at the cursor location for more accurate blobs  
   g2d.fill(blob);
  }
 }
```

I have a `Blob` class which keeps track of the user's current brush settings and where the user previously dragged his mouse so as to remember to draw a blob there.

```
final class Blob
{
 final Brush brush;
 final Point location;

 private Blob(Brush brush,Point location)
 {
  this.brush=brush;
  this.location=location;
 }

 private void paint(Graphics2D g){brush.paint(g,location);}
}
```

Finally my paint logic which is very simple.

Whenever the user drags his mouse add a blob at that current location with the current brush settings and inside `paint()` loop through all blobs and redraw them.

```
final class Painter extends Canvas
{
 private Brush brush=new Brush(5,Color.red);//Can Change
 private final ArrayList<Blob> blobs=new ArrayList(); 

 private Painter(){addMouseMotionListener(new Dragger());}

 @Override
 public void paint(Graphics g)
 {
  super.paint(g);

  blobs.forEach(blob->blob.paint(g));
 }

 private final class Dragger extends MouseAdapter
 {
  @Override
  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent m)
  {
   blobs.add(brush,m.getPoint());

   repaint();
  }    
 }
}
```

You can already see the problem here. The size of the list grows exponentially and my app quickly slows down. Is there an more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to create ms paint?  Intersting project, open source it.

Comment: A mini version for my chat application. Will release on GitHub hopefully by the end of this year :)

Comment: *"The size of the list grows exponentially"* No, it grows in a linear manner (unless there is something I missed in the code above). **Very** different things. *"..and my app quickly slows down."* I'm not convinced. Post a [mre] that we can test locally.

Answer (score 2):

The much more efficient way to do this is to use a BufferedImage for your drawing, and than painting the BufferedImage in paintComponent

Code taken from [PaintArea](https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/ex/PaintArea.java):

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (mSizeChanged) {
        handleResize();
    }
    g.drawImage(mImg, 0, 0, null);
}

protected class MListener extends MouseAdapter implements MouseMotionListener {
    Point mLastPoint;
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
        Graphics g = mImg.getGraphics();
        if ((me.getModifiers() & InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK) != 0) {
            g.setColor(mColor1);
        } else {
            g.setColor(mColor2);
            
        }
        Point p = me.getPoint();
        if (mLastPoint == null) {
            g.fillOval(p.x - mBrushSize / 2, p.y - mBrushSize / 2, mBrushSize, mBrushSize);
            //g.drawLine(p.x, p.y, p.x, p.y);
        }
        else {
            g.drawLine(mLastPoint.x, mLastPoint.y, p.x, p.y);
            //g.fillOval(p.x - mBrushSize / 2, p.y - mBrushSize / 2, mBrushSize, mBrushSize);
            double angle = MathUtils.angle(mLastPoint, p);
            if (angle < 0) {
                angle += 2 * Math.PI;
            }
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            double distance = MathUtils.distance(mLastPoint, p) * 1.5;
            if (angle < Math.PI / 4 || angle > 7 * Math.PI / 4 || Math.abs(Math.PI - angle) < Math.PI / 4) {
                for (int i = 0; i < mBrushSize / 2; i ++) {
                    g.drawLine(mLastPoint.x, mLastPoint.y + i, p.x, p.y + i);
                    g.drawLine(mLastPoint.x, mLastPoint.y - i, p.x, p.y - i);
                }
            }
            else {
                for (int i = 0; i < mBrushSize / 2; i ++) {
                    g.drawLine(mLastPoint.x + i, mLastPoint.y, p.x + i, p.y);
                    g.drawLine(mLastPoint.x  - i, mLastPoint.y, p.x - i, p.y);
                }                   
            }
        }
        mLastPoint = p;
        g.dispose();
        repaint();
    }
    
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {}
    
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
        mLastPoint = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes the problem here is I need to be able to "UNDO" my previous operation. The story here is I am creating an mini image editor for my chat application where the user can do simple draw operations on an image before sending it. I need to able to UNDO every step of paint when he presses Ctrl+z like Ms paint basically. Here I can undo only the whole paint operation by redrawing the original image. Suggestions?

Comment: @RVISHAL Take a look at PaintArea2 in same sourceforge project / directory as PaintArea, which as I recall included undo functionality. Personally I've always found undo to be tricky to implement in terms of the right about to undo - not too little, but not too much

Comment: Thank you i did take a look at it and it was tricky all right, I think i will skip the whole undo operation and use your approach. I found an alternative to remove the paint by simply painting over it with the an [subSection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) of the original image based on where the user drags and it works well. Upvote